# RadAsyncUpload throws HTTP 500 with a red dot beside the uploaded file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have used the RadProcessManager to configure the RadAsyncUpload, It's working fine locally. however after publishing on internet (On a dedicated server), Uploading files shows a red dot beside the uploaded file. and i can see 2 errors in the page console:

1- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

2- Uncaught Error while uploading, HTTP Error code is: 500

I have set the permissions of the temp and the target folder to full control for IUser.

I am using IIS 7, What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd handler is registered in the web.config you have on the production server. Alternatively try removing it and drag a new one on your .aspx page. Look [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-web-resources-troubleshooting.html) for references.